# Sum columns with similar names

Tags: r, sum, aggregate

I have a numeric vector `var`with names (output from predict.cv.glmnet)

```
var<-c(5.74,0.00,0.15,0.00,0.04,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.81,0.00)
names(var)<- cbind("(Intercept)","as.factor(holiday)1","as.factor(season)2","as.factor(season)3","as.factor(season)4","as.factor(weathersit)2", "as.factor(weathersit)3","windspeed","temp","hum")

(Intercept)    as.factor(holiday)1     as.factor(season)2     as.factor(season)3     as.factor(season)4      as.factor(weathersit)2 
   5.74              0.00                    0.15                       0.00                  0.04                   0.00 
as.factor(weathersit)3              windspeed                   temp                    hum 
           0.00                       0.00                      1.81                    0.00
```

I want to extract names of variables with non-zero values and also aggregate factors levels (i.e. if at least one level of a factor is non-zero, then the whole factor should be included. The output should omit factor levels. I am looking for a piece of code which would give me this as a result:

```
"(Intercept)"        "as.factor(season)"         "temp"
```

I also have a variable with factor names `fac` available:

```
fac<-c("as.factor(holiday)","as.factor(season)","as.factor(weathersit)")


 "as.factor(holiday)"    "as.factor(season)"     "as.factor(weathersit)"
```

and was thinking to aggregate factors with similar name while omitting their levels and check if the sum of the aggregated factors is >0 but I can't go about coding it.

Comment: Please consider making a reproducible example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played around with `which` and regular expressions:

```
var<-c(5.74,0.00,0.15,0.00,0.04,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.81,0.00)
names(var)<- cbind("(Intercept)","as.factor(holiday)1","as.factor(season)2","as.factor(season)3","as.factor(season)4","as.factor(weathersit)2", "as.factor(weathersit)3","windspeed","temp","hum")

X <- names(var)[which(var!=0)]
n <- grep( "as[.]factor.*", X )
X[n] <- gsub( ")[0-9]+$", ")", X[n] )

X <- unique(X)
X

#[1] "(Intercept)"       "as.factor(season)" "temp"
```

`which` selects the nonzero components.
`grep` is used to find the indices of factors. Then `gsub` removes the factor levels.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It does the job for the provided example. Do you know how I could use gsub to generalize this to cases where factors levels are not numeric? Let's say that my variable names are now:
`names(var)<- cbind("(Intercept)","as.factor(holiday)1","as.factor(season)winter","as.factor(season)spring","as.factor(season)summer","as.factor(weathersit)2", "as.factor(weathersit)3","windspeed","temp","hum")`

Comment: Okay I tried `X[n] <- gsub( ").+$", ")", X[n] )` and it seems to work alright.